# Lazy loading not loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, lazy-loading

I am using [lazy loading plugin](http://jquery.eisbehr.de/lazy/#promo) in my project. I have a carousel  with images there. I need to lazy load images in the carousel. This is the html:

```
@foreach($issues as $issue)
      <div class="swiper-slide magazine-image lazy-carousel">
        <div
          class="slider-image-wrap js-magazine-selector"
          data-id='{{ $issue->first()->magazine->id }}'
          data-slug='{{ str_slug($issue->first()->magazine->name) }}'
          data-name='{{ $issue->first()->magazine->name }}'
          data-summary='{{ $issue->first()->magazine->summary ?: '' }}'
          data-magazine-image='{{ $issue->first()->image  }}'
          data-magazine-visiolink='{{ $issue->first()->magazine->visio_link_prefix }}'
          data-issue-image='{{ $issue->first()->magazine->image ?: '' }}'
        >
          <img data-src="/imagecache/medium/{{ $issue->first()->image  }}">
          <div class="magazine-overlay">
            <div>
              <p>{{ $issue->first()->magazine->name }}</p>
              <a href="#">Se magasinet </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
@endforeach
```

This is the script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.lazy-carousel').Lazy({
    scrollDirection: 'horizontal',
    effect: 'fadeIn',
    effectTime: 2000,
    threshold: 0
  });
});
```

But, that doesn't work, images are not loaded at all. How can I fix that?

Comment: Any errors inside your development console perhaps? (ctrl + shift + j)

Comment: no errors in the console

Answer (score 1):

**Lazy dev here!**

As far as I see, you have two issues in your project.

- First, Lazy will listen to `scroll` events of the users by default. The plugin can't notice that the slider is changing. You need to tell this manually for your aproach. I don't know your slider, but you need to call a `function`, when the slider is changed.
- Second, you want to lazy-load the images, but you tell Lazy to handle `.lazy-carousel`, what is the wrapper `div`, and not the images inside.

To fix this create your Lazy instance and pass it to a variable and tell Lazy to handle images:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var lazy = $('.lazy-carousel img').Lazy({
    scrollDirection: 'horizontal',
    effect: 'fadeIn',
    effectTime: 2000,
    threshold: 0,
    chainable: false
  });
});
```

Whenever your slider changes, you need to call the public function `.update()` of Lazy, to handle the now visible images:

```
window.lazy.update();
```

This should work as expected then.

Answer (score -2):

You create multiple carousel with a single image (each) instead of one carousel with multiple images. Try this:

```
      <div class="swiper-slide magazine-image lazy-carousel">
        <div
          class="slider-image-wrap js-magazine-selector"
          data-id='{{ $issue->first()->magazine->id }}'
          data-slug='{{ str_slug($issue->first()->magazine->name) }}'
          data-name='{{ $issue->first()->magazine->name }}'
          data-summary='{{ $issue->first()->magazine->summary ?: '' }}'
          data-magazine-image='{{ $issue->first()->image  }}'
          data-magazine-visiolink='{{ $issue->first()->magazine->visio_link_prefix }}'
          data-issue-image='{{ $issue->first()->magazine->image ?: '' }}'
        >
        @foreach($issues as $issue)
          <img data-src="/imagecache/medium/{{ $issue->first()->image  }}">
          <div class="magazine-overlay">
            <div>
              <p>{{ $issue->first()->magazine->name }}</p>
              <a href="#">Se magasinet </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          @endforeach
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: I am not creating multiple carousels and that is not a problem, the problem is that lazy loading doesn't work, foreach loop has nothing do with it, since I have no problems creating carousel otherwise, if I remove the lazy-carousel class